# Manage Packages not workling

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

Any ideas why this thing would spin forever?

I tried reset cache - no effect. Does it on a new project too.

[image]

Comment: Is your GitHub account configured properly? It’s trying to show you your repositories.

Comment: Seems to be working. I can fetch changes without an error.

Comment: Also, the other three options in the Swift Packages menu all work.

Comment: Well can you paste in a package url at least?

Comment: I reinstalled XCode and it didn't fix it. But pasting in URL works. I'm not sure if it worked before or not. I don't think it did because I tried it, but perhaps I made a mistake.

Comment: Well, all you're ever really likely to need to do here is paste in a URL, so I'd say you're in good shape. I don't know why the list never appears but it doesn't contain anything you need.